# Create 2 DataFrame from the existing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I would like to create a 2 dataframe, df1 and df2 from the old dataframe. df1 should have only one name and no duplicates. df2 should have the remaining duplicate names.

My input:
df:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 24 |
| Amy | 34 |
| jack | 66 |
| mo | 76 |
| mo | 88 |
| mo | 98 |
| linn | 33 |

Output, df1:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 24 |
| Jack | 66 |
| mo | 76 |
| linn | 33 |

Output, df2:

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| Amy | 34 |
| mo | 88 |
| mo | 98 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No duplicates:

```
    df1 = df[~df.duplicated('Name')]
```

- Duplicates:

```
    df2 = df[df.duplicated('Name')]
```